# WinRT's WebView is not loading the .css file when running on an actual Tablet

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I am using a WebView control under WinRT to display html pages that are loaded from a sub folder of my Assets folder.  When I run my app on a Windows 8 PC or on the tablet emulator everything works fine.  However, when I am running on an actual Surface tablet, the pages do not seem to be loading the .css file and are, therefore, not formatted properly.

Is there something that I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Sadly, I don't think anyone can help without access to the URL with the limited amount of information you have provided. It could be invalid CSS, CSS not loading all together or another problem such a responsive CSS not working... Please if possible provide the URL so we can check the site in question.

Comment: Provide details, what's de CSS, how are you loading it, how did you deploy the app to the Surface, provide CODE, tell us what u've tried, etc. Otherwise, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Well I can give you the details of the CSS file, but, as I said, it works just fine when I run the exact same app on both a Windows 8 PC and the tablet emulator.  It only fails to work when running on an actual table.  I have also found that if I include the contents of the CSS file within the HTML file, it works fine everywhere.  So I am pretty sure the problem does not lie with the CSS file, but rather with the loading of it when running on actual hardward.  Also, there is no URL to look at because the file are being loaded from the Assets folder of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Verify that the CSS file is being included in the app you're running on the Surface.  [Create an app package](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt-harrington/archive/2012/04/14/how-to-share-your-metro-style-windows-8-app-with-another-developer.aspx) and then look inside it.  To be thorough, copy the app package to your Surface and run it there to verify that the problem still occurs.
2. Run the Windows App Certification Kit (WACK) tool to uncover common problems.  This is just a wild guess, but maybe your CSS file has the wrong encoding, and this causes a problem on Windows RT.  Really, this is just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I ran the WACK and there were a couple of issues, but nothing that seems to be related to the html pages.  I will try and eliminate the issues and see if that changes anything. As for looking inside the package, I am not really sure how to do that.  When I create the package, it appears to be a large binary file.  How do I see inside?  I might add that if I take the css file and embed it within the HTML file it seem to work fine, even on the tablet.

Comment: I fixed all of the issues that the WACK flagged, and, as I suspected, it did not affect the loading of the pages.  The css file is still not being loaded.

Comment: To answer one of your questions, you can rename the appx as zip and then open with winzip and see the various pieces of content.

Comment: Ok, the mystery is solved.  When I looked in the package, low and behold the css files were missing.  It appears that when I switched from building for Win32 to ARM, Visual Studio removed those two files from the list of included files.  Oddly, as far as I can tell, those were the ONLY 2 files it removed.  Strange.  Anyway, thanks much for your help.